# Is it possible to get a list of all the Storyboard ID's in a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, interface-builder

Does anyone know how to get all the storyboard IDs in an Interface builder storyboard?  Its an XML file so I am guessing there's a way to parse it and grab the IDs that way.

My end goal is getting a list of all the view controllers in my app irrespective of whether they have been presented or not.

Comment: There appears to be no portable way of doing this (reading storyboard as an XML would be a hack). The reason for this is design philosophy behind IB: it's supposed to be a slave of the code, not the driver of it.

Comment: Sounds good.  I am trying to get a hold of all my view controllers so I can update dynamic text.  Thought this might be an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help - parses Storyboard in model you can use in Swift

https://github.com/Adorkable/StoryboardKit